# Wait for CockroachDB Command to Finish

Tags: slick-2.0, cockroachdb

I currently have a `.sql` file with the likes of:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS vw_example;

CREATE VIEW vw_example as
SELECT a FROM b;
```

When running this command as part of a flyway migration, if the view already exists, it fails, as if the create command is not waiting for the `DROP IF EXISTS` to finish.

I know SQL server has a `GO` type keyword. Is there a way to sort of tell cockroachdb to wait for the first command?

Comment: I don't think this is a batching issue in CockroachDB. Try copy-pasting the following several times into the [`cockroach sql`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/use-the-built-in-sql-client.html) shell (or [`demo`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/cockroach-demo.html) if you're on 19.2+): `\| echo "DROP VIEW IF EXISTS vw_example; CREATE VIEW vw_example as SELECT count(1) from pg_settings;"`. Are you sure slick is executing those statements in the stated order/from a file?

Comment: @PeterVandivier - I suppose so, but it all runs part of a Flyway migration. I'm not sure if there is code there to parse the file and run statements concurrently - wouldn't make much sense to me, but maybe? When I ran these using DataGrip they always worked as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the issue mentioned in the [link](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/39667), it is better to have the drop and create scripts in different migration files as flyway runs each migration in a single transaction.